# Users are added to Firebase Auth but not Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a register page in my Android application but I am struggling with a bug for a few days now.
When adding a user to Firebase, it shows up in the Auth page but the Realtime Database stays clear (no childs created)...
In the first press on the "Register" button, the user is added to the Auth but for some reason, no Toast shows up.
In the second press, a Toast pops saying "Failed to register" (because the account is already created).

How do I add the users to the Database? Is something wrong with my code?

Here's the code:

```
private void registerUser() {
    final String email = edEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = edPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String confirmPassword = edConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        edEmail.setError("An Email is required!");
        edEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        edEmail.setError("Please provide a valid Email!");
        edEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        edPassword.setError("A password is required!");
        edPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.length() < 8) {
        edPassword.setError("The password is too short!");
        edPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
        edConfirmPassword.setError("The passwords in both fields must match!");
        edConfirmPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }


    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    User user = new User(email, password);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(user)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "User has been registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.i("RegisterPage", "User has been registered successfully");
                                    goToLoginPage();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "Failed to register user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.i("RegisterPage", "Failed to register user!");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "Failed to register!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("RegisterPage", "Failed to register!");
                }
            }
    });
}
```

After the first press on "Register", it goes into the first `if(task.isSuccessful())`, meaning the task is successful. Then it just skips the second `OnComplete` (The Database one). After the second press on "Register", the first `if(task.isSuccessful())` is false so it goes to the `else` below and pops a toast (happens because the user is already created and is in the Auth page on Firebase). After the first press `task.getException()` returns nothing, after the second it returns:

```
2021-05-24 02:37:00.678 24492-24492/com.fulminatix.gymlog W/RegisterPage: createUserWithEmail:failure
    com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email address is already in use by another account.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzto.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzux.zzl(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuu.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztl.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzoc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:23)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzul.zzn(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpt.zzl(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztp.zzg(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzqg.accept(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacj.doExecute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaf.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:167)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:139)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zabg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:99)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zabe(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:40)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:19)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaf.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzg.zzj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:24)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.zzo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:11)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:49)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zzi.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:8)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on both `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` and run in the debugger, it should stop on one or both of those lines. From there step through the code, and check which branch is takes. Also not that if a task fails, its `task.getException()` returns details about the reason for the failure - which are probably really useful here.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
After the first press on "Register", it goes into the first `if(task.isSuccessful())`, meaning the task is successful. Then it just skips the second `OnComplete` (The Database one).
After the second press on "Register", the first `if(task.isSuccessful())` is false so it goes to the `else` below and pops a toast (happens because the user is already created and is in the Auth page on Firebase).
After the first press `task.getException()` returns nothing, after the second it returns:
`SHOWN IN THE QUESTION BECAUSE ITS TOO LONG`
@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: 1) I recommend focussing on only the first run. Since you expect that to succeed, the fact that the second run provides (expected) problems is not relevant. 2) Did you put a breakpoint on the inner `if(task.isSuccessful())`? If it never reaches that breakpoint, this usually means that the database SDK can't reach its backend servers.

Comment: I did. It never reaches it... So how do I fix it? I have `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'` in my app level `build.gradle` and I can see the Database tree in Firebase's website (It's just empty..) @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I tested the Database and it didn't log the info in Firebase. 
```FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```
@FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. I found the problem.
I was using the europe-west1 database and not the default us-central1 and apparently:

> To get a reference to a database other than a us-central1 default dstabase, you must pass the database URL to getInstance() (or Kotlin+KTX database()) . For a us-central1 default database, you can call getInstance() (or database) without arguments.
> You can find your Realtime Database URL in the Realtime Database section of the Firebase console. It will have the form https://.firebaseio.com (for us-central1 databases) or https://.firebasedatabase.app (for databases in all other locations).

Adding my Realtime Database URL into the `getInstance()` fixed my problem.
Example:
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://XXXXXXXX.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/")`

Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for raising up the problem!